# Deploying clean meteor 0.9 to heroku

Tags: heroku, meteor, continuous-integration, buildpack, codeship

I am creating a very small and clean meteor app and have recently updated to v0.9 of meteor to be able to get rid of meteorite as "package manager".

For me it is really important in a way not to have any deployment specific stuff wired up into the sourcecode if it is possible.

What I am trying to do in a way is to have a good and clean Continuous Integration running. Right now I am using Codeship to run the tests and then push to heroku. But since I updated top meteor v0.9 there not seems to be a working buildpack.

Is it a reasonable way to create a buildpack on my own? That one would not have to do more than just install node, npm and meteor. Or is there another way to have the app bundled on a "build server" (can codeship do that?) and then have it somehow pushed to heroku as normal node.js app with all the necessities and dependencies?

**Concerning the buildpack way:**

I have been trying to install meteor via

```
curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
```

But when I run

```
meteor deploy --directory deploy
```

I get

```
bundle: You're not in a Meteor project directory.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This buildpack (which I authored) works for meteor >0.9 using meteor's native packager; no meteorite:

https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked out of the box with my Meteor 1.0 app!

Answer (score 1):

You could start off with the existing buildpack (or one of the many forks of it).

It should be relatively easy without meteorite since you would no longer have to worry about it, its just getting rid of meteorite and updating the version of node. https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite

Regarding deploying to heroku. `meteor deploy` is meant to deploy to *.meteor.com or via Meteor's upcoming commercial product. Deploying to heroku is also relatively easy.

Deploying to heroku is setting up the buildpack, adding the git remote and git pushing to it. Also easy, perhaps easier, than `meteor deploy`.

During the git push process heroku will take your meteor app, bundle it, download node and run it (as in the buildpack). It's quite easy that way. One nice thing without meteorite is I imagine the build process is much faster.

Comment: Hi Akshat, thanks for the answer. I actually started to pursue this idea her [link](https://github.com/haynzz/buildpack-meteorite/blob/master/bin/compile).

Comment: Hi Akshat. I got it working for me now. Would be good if also somebody else would check it out and maybe clean it a bit. I feel it's hacky: https://github.com/haynzz/buildpack-meteor-0.9

Comment: @haynzz - if it works, make a pull request to the upstream repo. A lot of people are waiting for a fix. Thanks!

Comment: @haynzz I believe this buildpack works with v0.9+ of meteor which would mean no support for meteorite, however the README.md still refers to meteorite; you may want to update the READ.md file as I presumed it wouldn't work with version 0.9+ because of this.